# C# Regex Alpahnumeric String

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to check whether a string contains the following Groups.
All Strings MUST contain exactly 2 *##*

**String 1)**

```
##Some_Foo_Text_1##
```

=> Expected result: String contains 1 Valid group

**String 2)**

```
##Some_Foo_Text_2#E+1##
```

=> Expected result: String contains 1 Valid group

**String 3)**

```
##Some_Foo_Text_3#e-1##
```

=> Expected result: String contains 1 Valid Group

**String 4)**

```
##Some_Foo_Text_4##E+1##
```

=>Expected result: String contains 1 valid Group (##Some_Foo_Text_4##) and 1 invalid Group (E+1##) the invalid Group is discarded

Now i came up with this regex

```
/([A-Za-z\+\-0-9])+/g
```

According to [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) this does not match my string. 
Could you help me to take care of the ## at the beginning and End?

Comment: You regex doesn't containt any `#`. Is this wildcard for something in your examples or what? Could you please provide more concrete examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex will match everything between two occurrences of "##";

```
(##.*?##)
```

In your last example string `##Some_Foo_Text_4##`becomes a match but not `E+1##`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
^##(?<content>.+?)##(?!#)
```

Explanation:

```
^           // begin of the line
##          // match literaly
(           // to capture group
?<content>  // with name content
.           // any char
+?          // as few times as possible
##          // match literlly
(?!         // assert that 
#           // this regex will not match
)           // end of negative lookahead
```

Example:

```
var regex = new Regex("^##(?<content>.+?)##(?!#)");
var input = new[]
{
    "##Some_Foo_Text_21##",
    "##Some_Foo_Text_2#E+1##",
    "##Some_Foo_Text_3#e-1##",
    "##Some_Foo_Text_4##E+1##",
};

foreach (var line in input)
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(line).Groups["content"].Value);
```

Output is

> Some_Foo_Text_21
>
> Some_Foo_Text_2#E+1
>
> Some_Foo_Text_3#e-1
>
> Some_Foo_Text_4

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work for all lines posted `(?<=##)([A-Za-z0-9_])*(?=#)` here is an example 
https://regexr.com/47aml

Although if it is multiline you need to enable the multiline option to get proper results.